# What is the meaning of "on or after the 1st of January in the previous calendar year"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

There is one view that, if applied today, the sentence means from 1st January 2013 to 31st December 2013.

There is another view that, if applied today, the sentence means any time after 1st January 2013 (ie 1st January 2013 until today (12th June 2014)).

My question is, is there a definitive meaning of the phrase?

Comment: You've overlooked the word *of*, between the day and the month.

Comment: It is quite obviously ambiguous as you say yourself. What is your question, then?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance I thought 1st January 2013 to today. However, the words "in the previous calendar year" suggested that 1st Jan to 31st Dec 2013 was meant.  However (again), that would be definitely true if there were a comma prior to "in the previous...", and probably false without the comma.  Hence, I came back to my original opinion.

Therefore, I would conclude that, at best, the statement refers to any time from 1st Jan 2013 to today, but is poorly worded as it leaves the reader in doubt.

Comment: The best evidence for this opinion is that "on or after 1st January" is redundant if they are talking about the previous calendar year. All dates are on or after Jan 1st.

Answer (score 1):

The incomplete example you've posted could be interpreted both ways. A complete example might include some more context that gives a little more information about the meaning.